# Coffeescript Object as a private member, is it possible?

Tags: oop, coffeescript

I'm used to being able to in Java define an object which can contain other objects as members, for example (psuedocode):

```
class Zoo{
private List<Animal> animals;
}
class Animal {
private double weight;
private double height;
private double species;
}
```

Then you could have a constructor for zoo which takes X animals and adds them to an animal collection and have it's own methods.

In coffeescript I can't seem to be able to do this, is this a limitation of javascript?

Comment: There are no private properties in JavaScript, and by extension, CoffeeScript.

Comment: Just found [this](http://evanhahn.com/private-members-in-coffeescript/) about private members, kinda useful here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hope I understood your question.

in Coffeescript you may write

```
class Animal
  name: ''

class Zoo
  animals: [] #notice you do not specify type!

  constructor: (animalList) ->
    @animals = animalList #and animal list is an array of Animal class instances


zoo = new Zoo([new Animal()])
console.log(zoo.animals.length) #should be eq to 1
```

If you want animals to be private same as it would be in Java or C#, I would recommend not using classes but:

```
Zoo = (animals) ->

  return {
    getAnimals: -> animals
    addToAnimals: (animal) -> animals.push(animal)
  }
```

Comment: Also you can make it more implicit: ```class Zoo
  constructor: (@animals) ->```

Comment: @welldan97 Yes, I know, but Craig Harley seems to not know general concepts so I wanted to do it as explicit as possible